# Accessing Rails engine's URL helpers in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to access the url helpers in my engine to set up [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors). Right now, I've hard-coded the strings for one of the urls in the rack-cors middleware configuration. I have read [the order in which Rails initializers are run](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.22.2/configuring.html#initializers), and at this point in the load order I should have the engine routes available to me. I thought I would have them available at the event `add_routing_paths`, but I couldn't find the routes after digging around using pry. Another statement that leads me to think I'm doing this incorrectly is that the docs say: "Some parts of your application, notably routing, are not yet set up at the point where the after_initialize block is called." According to [this list](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.22.2/classes/Rails/Application.html):

1. require "config/boot.rb" to setup load paths
2. require railties and engines
3. Define Rails.application as "class MyApp::Application < Rails::Application"
4. Run config.before_configuration callbacks
5. Load config/environments/ENV.rb
6. Run config.before_initialize callbacks
7. Run Railtie#initializer defined by railties, engines and application.
   One by one, each engine sets up its load paths, routes and runs its config/initializers/* files.
8. Custom Railtie#initializers added by railties, engines and applications are executed
9. Build the middleware stack and run to_prepare callbacks
10. Run config.before_eager_load and eager_load! if eager_load is true
11. Run config.after_initialize callbacks

I'm trying to hook into (7), but perhaps routes aren't available until (11)?

```rb
module Zillow
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Zillow

    # Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    initializer "zillow.cors", after: :set_routes_reloader do |app|
      require 'pry'; binding.pry
      app.config.app_middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
        allow do
          origins 'localhost:3000'
          resource '/zillow/search_results', methods: :get
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the output of my routes

```
zillow  /zillow Zillow::Engine

Routes for Zillow::Engine:
              api_deep_comps GET /api/deep_comps(.:format)               zillow/api#deep_comps
               api_zestimate GET /api/zestimate(.:format)                zillow/api#zestimate
          api_search_results GET /api/search_results(.:format)           zillow/api#search_results
api_updated_property_details GET /api/updated_property_details(.:format) zillow/api#updated_property_details
```

Answer (score 9):

You can fire your own event when routes are loaded and then subscribe to that event during initialization to get routes data. For that:

1. Add this to the end of `config/routes.rb` file (outside of `routes.draw` block)

```ruby
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument 'routes_loaded.application'
```

2. Subscribe to this event in initialization code and use URL helpers!

```ruby
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'routes_loaded.application' do
  Rails.logger.info Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.home_path
end
```

For more information see:

- [Subscribing to an event](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#subscribing-to-an-event)
- [Creating custom events](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#creating-custom-events)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I noticed your links are pointing to the Rails Guides for the latest version of Rails, version 5. The original question and follow up response I submitted sought a solution in Rails 3.

Comment: Ah, true. I've checked now and there is no similar guide for Rails 3. But it seems, that this API is already available in Rails 3: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html. So the solution probably applies to Rails 3 as well.

And if it doesn't, then maybe an alternative can be written manually by creating a class with a method in the initializer and then calling this method after routes are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

#### Load it just *after* initialize.

I needed to use `root_url` in my initializer but it wasn't properly initialized. I tried using the [Pub / Sub method that Anton Styagun suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511010/293280) but even when that's called the URL Helpers were not properly initialized.

Instead, I opted to load my initializer file manually *just after* the Rails app itself has initialized. This takes a few steps:

1. Move your initializer from `config/initializers/` to `lib/`.
2. Require your file in `environment.rb` just after your application initializes. Ours looks something like this:

   ```rb
   CNTRAL::Application.initialize!

   require "my_initializer" # Omit the `lib/` because that's the load path it looks in.
   ```
3. Now, inside of `my_initializer.rb` I was able to call `root_url` by doing this:

   ```rb
   Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url
   ```

   *NOTE: It's important not to just use `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`. It raised an exception on me.*

I also added a comment in both the initializer and the `environment.rb` of where this was loaded/required so it's more obvious to myself in the future and other engineers.

#### Alternative Method

You can also use the following method and it works well:

In your `application.rb` file, add:

```rb
config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.reload_routes! # Necessary to load the Routes.
  require  "my_initializer"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

After looking into this further and reading [the rack-cors example done in Rails3](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/examples/rails3/config/application.rb#L66), it may not be possible to retrieve the route helpers inside the initializer at any point in time.